# Refused to load the stylesheet in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, content-security-policy

I have a Rails application and I just changed the version to `5.2.3` and version of Ruby to `2.6.3` in `.ruby-version` file and `GemFile` and tried `bundle install` again.

Now I`m facing this error:
[image]

And this is my `application.erb` heading part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ASP Kit</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="font-src 'self' http://xxxx 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; ">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zxcvbn/4.2.0/zxcvbn.js' %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <% end %>

  </head>
```

Also I uncommitted some codes in file `content_security_policy.rb` :

```
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |policy|
  policy.default_src :self, :https
  policy.font_src    :self, :https, :data
  policy.img_src     :self, :https, :data
  policy.object_src  :none
  policy.script_src  :self, :https
  policy.style_src   :self, :https

  # Specify URI for violation reports
  # policy.report_uri "/csp-violation-report-endpoint"
end
```

I tried some meta tags but did not work!

Comment: Do you have a file in your project directory located in `config/initializers` called `csp.rb`?

Comment: no I do not  have csp.rb there!

Comment: @Danoram I have this file content_security_policy.rb

Comment: Good. csp.erb is the new name for content_security_policy.erb but you are using an older version of rails so just leave it. Have you tried removing `<%= csp_meta_tag %>` ?

Comment: I mean csp was the old name... sorry

Comment: try changing `policy.script_src  :self, :https` to `policy.script_src  :self, :https, :unsafe_inline` and `policy.style_src   :self, :https` to `policy.style_src   :self, :https, :unsafe_inline`

Comment: I removed ``<%= csp_meta_tag %>`` but nothing changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197970/discussion-between-danoram-and-sami-al-morshedi).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to Ruby version. I wrote this app in Ruby 2.5.5 and then updated my it to version 2.6.3 then then problem appeared. I do not know any solution for this bug on version 2.6.3 but I downgrade to 2.5.5 and it fixed for now.